# How to store data for my application securely

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos, property-list

I am creating a game for iOS and OSX in Xcode using Objective-C.

A major concern I’m undergoing is finding methods to prevent cheaters from hacking my game.

I’ve recently learnt how to save/read information through property lists. In the OSX version of the app, I can directly access these lists and edit them by right clicking on the app, going to Package Contents and then Resources. My original plan was to store/edit data like high scores, etc. Obviously, a major flaw with this would be that users of this app would be able to cheat easily.

In addition to this, I have played many games for iOS where I have seen users cheat on scoreboards, or sometimes even users who seem to have hacked the game as they have large amounts of money which they definitely could’t have acquired otherwise (the example I’m thinking of is a competitive tower defence game where both players start off with 0 cash and earn a set amount every few seconds. Players have definitely hacked if they acquire 100x the cash than possible in the first few seconds).

Hence I’m worried about the security of data I’m storing in my game, and looking for a solution to this, and the following are ones I’m considering.

1. I quite like property lists, but would it be more secure to use some other form of data storage method? Or would it be just the same because hackers can still decode these files?
2. Is there some way to hide these property lists/data inside the application so that hackers cannot access them? Or would they be still eventually find them if they look hard enough?
3. If the above 2 are not possible or still leave the possibility of cheaters, then would the best solution be to encode the data in these lists so they can only be read with some key? Eg. every score I store would be encoded by dividing by -129, whilst they would be read by the app by multiplying by -129.

Please can someone recommend a solution to this problem for both OSX and iOS?

Comment: I would suggest  to use plist for storing data but  for security reason before storing data in pilst you may use some encoding-decoding algorithms in your code. If any hacker is able to get your plist, s/he would not be able to decode your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say the best solution for this would be to store these value on server and these will be only accessible after authentication and on a HTTPS connection.

The disadvantage in the other approach will be that it won't be available offline.

So if you wish to have offline access as well then you can very well use plist as well. The only thing you will have to do is to encrypt the file and write it to the documents directory. You can convert your plists to data and then encrypt and write it. The key can be the user password which you can store in the iOS keychain.

The above method will be pretty secure, in fact very secure but nothing is unbreakable. Hoping this helps.

You can use this [library](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor) for encryption.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there no place where I can "hide" the file if I'm looking for offline access? And with the server method, can hackers not try to change values which are sent to the server from the app?

Comment: there is no places as such, but you can always convert your file to text and save in the keychain which is highly secure. But do this only if the text is not too large, I mean just don't use misuse it. You will always know when you are not supposed to do it. In that case go for the encryption method.

Comment: I was previously planning on storing the game setup in here as well (by this I mean for example, how many enemies/difficulty, etc etc in levels)... but seeing that I can't hide the files, maybe it would be best to hardcode this information into the code itself (if I don't bother coding the info)?

Comment: I would not advise hardcoding the information in code, because that can be easily looked up using reverse engineering methods. That is why I said that you use the password as key and store it in Keychain. believe me your best bet is encrypted files in documents directory.

Comment: Ok thank you. I don't quite get what you mean by hard engineering methods. Does this mean its possible to retrieve the code from the .app version of the file after the code is compiled!?

Comment: Yes.. someone with good enough knowledge can do it, but it is not easy. Refer this: http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1594/possibilities-for-reverse-engineering-an-ipa-file-to-its-source

Comment: Ok thank you. It all makes better sense now. One last question: even if I do encode the information in the plist, can cheaters still "reverse state" of the game by reverting the plist to how it was 1 day ago, say, in order to cover up some bad plays or something. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: For that to happen they will have to keep a copy of the file everyday, which seems like to much of a work to do. I might let go of that use case. Data encryption would be much easier in your case as compared to encoding the contents. Also if my answers have helped you can up vote and mark my as an accepted one.

Comment: Ok, thank you for all the help, and the great answers! I guess game data isn't as safe as thought without encryption.